# opening <a> element appearing in the page in the browser but not sure why

Tags: html, asp.net

having a bit of an issue. On my website I have added a new post but on the page where you select which post to view only the post title is clickable, it should be the whole div that is clickable not just the title. There is also an  opening element that appears at the start of the post content that should not be there. I have included an image below, the mystery  element is highlighted in yellow.
[image]

I have looked at it with firebug and the  element that is supposed to wrap the entire div is closed after the header and the mystery opening  element appears but I am unable to find out how or why. Any help anyone is able to offer would be awesome and very much appreciated

The elements are inside a repeater. the first item renders fine but not the second.

Go to [this page](http://www.griffithswebdesign.com/Blog/4) to view the page in question.

Comment: Firebug may be closing the element if you're just looking at the DOM.  You need to look at the source with View Source

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.griffithswebdesign.com%2FBlog%2F4

Comment: you havent closed your `<a>`..

Comment: I don't know why its not closed. the first repeater item is fine but not this one.

Comment: So why is the second repeater item different to the first? As the comments have said I haven't closed the <a> but that should not be happening. It only happens on this particular item. What gives?